# Как отключить overflow-x

Tags: reactjs, веб-программирование, sass

Всем привет! Я сейчас делаю сайт и столкнулся с такой проблемой, что в мобильной версии не могу отключить overflow-x, точнее в коде он отключен, но на практике всё равно работает.

**Ссылка на веб-сайт:**
https://jintropine.kz/

```css
$red: #588EF7
$light_red: #EEA6A1
$main_cream: #F4F5F8
$main_blue: #00346E
$selected_blue: #008AA2
$background: #FFFF
$button_hover: #2B6FF5

// Margins
$eightclamp: clamp(4px,0.4166666666666667vw,16px)
$sixteenclamp: clamp(8px,0.8333333333333334vw,32px)
$twentyclamp: clamp(10px,1.0416666666666667vw,40px)

$thirtytwoclamp: clamp(16px,1.6666666666666667vw,64px)
$sixtyfourclamp: clamp(32px,3.3333333333333335vw,128px)
$onetwoeightclamp: clamp(64px,6.666666666666667vw,256px)
$twofivesixclamp: clamp(128px,13.333333333333334vw,512px)

// Fonts
@import url('https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Roboto+Condensed:ital,wght@0,300;0,400;0,700;1,300;1,400;1,700&display=swap')
@import url('https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Raleway:ital,wght@0,100;0,200;0,300;0,400;0,500;0,600;0,700;0,800;0,900;1,100;1,200;1,300;1,400;1,500;1,600;1,700;1,800;1,900&family=Roboto+Condensed:ital,wght@0,300;0,400;0,700;1,300;1,400;1,700&display=swap')

*
    margin: 0
    padding: 0

    body
        width: 100%
        height: 100%
        font-family: 'Raleway', sans-serif
        background-color: $background !important
        font-display: fallback
        overflow-x: hidden !important

        button, a
            cursor: pointer
            transition: 0.3s all
            border: none

        .main-screen
            width: 100%
            height: auto
            display: flex
            margin: auto
            flex-direction: column

            .arrow-blue
                position: absolute
                width: clamp(97.5px,10.15625vw,390px)
                height: clamp(120.5px,12.552083333333334vw,482px)
                left: clamp(418.115px,43.553645833333334vw,1672.46px)
                top: clamp(243.5px,25.364583333333332vw,974px)

            .separator
                width: 86.45833333333333%
                height: 1px
                background-color: $main_blue
                margin: auto
                margin-top: $thirtytwoclamp

            .container
                width: 86.45833333333333%
                height: auto
                display: flex
                margin: auto
                margin-top: clamp( 50px,5.208333333333333vw,200px)
                justify-content: space-between

                .proto-photo
                    width: clamp(319.5px,33.28125vw,1278px)
                    height: clamp(249.795px,26.0203125vw,999.18px)

                .main-heading
                    width: clamp(350px,36.458333333333336vw,1400px)
                    height: clamp(80px,8.333333333333334vw,320px)
                    font-family: 'Roboto Condensed'
                    font-style: normal
                    font-weight: 700
                    font-size: clamp(32.5px,3.3854166666666665vw,130px)
                    color: #1e1e1e

                    .hormone
                        color: $red

                .description
                    width: clamp(323px,33.645833333333336vw,1292px)
                    height: clamp(54px,5.625vw,216px)
                    font-family: 'Raleway'
                    font-style: normal
                    font-weight: 400
                    font-size: clamp(11.5px,1.1979166666666667vw,46px)
                    font-size: clamp(11.5px,1.1979166666666667vw,46px)
                    margin-top: $thirtytwoclamp
                    color: #1e1e1e

                .buttons
                    width: auto
                    height: auto
                    display: flex
                    margin-top: clamp(42.5px,4.427083333333333vw,170px)

                    .main-button
                        width: clamp(203.5px,21.197916666666668vw,814px)
                        height: $sixtyfourclamp
                        text-decoration: none !important
                        background-color: $red
                        display: flex
                        align-items: center
                        border-radius: 52px
                        justify-content: center
                        font-weight: 500
                        border: none
                        color: $background
                        font-family: 'Roboto Condensed'
                        font-style: normal
                        font-size: clamp(13px,1.3541666666666667vw,52px)
                        margin-top: $sixtyfourclamp
                        &:hover
                            background-color: $button_hover

                        .telegram-icon
                            margin-right: clamp(6px,0.625vw,24px)

@media screen  and (max-width: 448px)

    .main-screen
        width: 100%
        height: 100vh
        display: flex
        margin: auto
        flex-direction: column

        .arrow-blue
            display: none !important

        .separator
            display: none

        .container
            width: 86.45833333333333%
            height: auto
            display: flex
            flex-direction: column

            .proto-photo
                display: none

            .main-content

                .main-heading
                    width: clamp(149.5px,69.85981308411215vw,598px) !important
                    height: clamp(118px,55.14018691588785vw,472px) !important
                    margin: auto
                    font-size: clamp(27.5px,12.850467289719626vw,110px) !important
                    text-align: center

                .description
                    width: clamp(150px,72.46376811594203vw,600px) !important
                    height: clamp(105px,49.06542056074766vw,420px) !important
                    text-align: center
                    margin: auto
                    font-weight: 400
                    font-size: clamp(11.5px,5.897435897435898vw,46px) !important
                    margin-top: clamp(32px,14.953271028037383vw,128px) !important

                .buttons
                    display: flex
                    flex-direction: column
                    align-items: center
                    justify-content: center
                    margin-top: clamp(145px,74.35897435897436vw,580px) !important

                    .main-button, .more-button
                        width: 84% !important
                        height: clamp(31.5px,14.719626168224298vw,126px) !important
                        font-size: clamp(12px,5.607476635514018vw,48px)
                        margin: auto
                        margin-top: clamp(45px,23.076923076923077vw,180px) !important

                    .main-button
                        height: clamp(34px,15.88785046728972vw,136px) !important

                    .more-button
                        width: 83% !important
                        margin-top: clamp(16px,7.4766355140186915vw,64px)
                        margin-bottom: clamp(32px,14.953271028037383vw,128px)
```